# Showing $\mathscr{P}_n=\langle\zeta, \tau, \pi, \xi\rangle$.

Tags: permutations, semigroups, finitely-generated, partial-functions

This is Exercise 1.9.13 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*.

### The Details:

> **Definition:** The *partial transformation semigroup* $\mathscr{P}_n$ is the set of all partial maps from $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ to itself, together with composition of partial transformations.

Let $\xi$ be the partial map $$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & \dots & n \\
2 & 3 & \dots & n
\end{pmatrix}$$ and let $\zeta$, $\tau$, $\pi$ be as defined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950124/showing-the-full-transformation-semigroup-mathscrt-n-langle-zeta-tau-pi).

> **Definition:** For each subset $Y$ of $X=\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$, define $\xi_{Y}$ by $1_{X\setminus Y}$; thus $\xi=\xi_{\{1\}}$.

### Some Lemmas:

> **Lemma 1:** We have $(1i)\xi(1i)=\xi_{\{i\}}$ for $i\in X$ and
>   $$\xi_Y=\prod_{i\in Y}\xi_{\{i\}}.$$

*Proof:* This is basic computation and the recognition that $$1_{X\setminus Y}=\prod_{i\in Y}1_{X\setminus \{i\}}.$$ $\square$

> **Lemma 2:** For each $\alpha$ in $\mathscr{P}_n$, let $\hat{\alpha}$, the *completion of $\alpha$*, be given by
>   $$x\hat{\alpha}=\begin{cases} x\alpha &: x\in \operatorname{dom} \alpha \\ x &: \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Then, for $Y=X\setminus \operatorname{dom} \alpha$, $$\alpha=\xi_Y\hat{\alpha}.$$

*Proof:* Let $x\in X$. Then
$$\begin{align}
x(\xi_Y\hat{\alpha})&=(x 1_{X\setminus Y})\hat{\alpha} \\
&=(x 1_{X\setminus (X\setminus \operatorname{dom} \alpha)})\hat{\alpha} \\
&=(x 1_{\operatorname{dom} \alpha})\hat{\alpha} \\
&=x\alpha.
\end{align}$$ $\square$

### The Question:

> Deduce (from **Lemma 1** and **Lemma 2**) that $\mathscr{P}_n=\langle\zeta, \tau, \pi, \xi\rangle$.

### Thoughts:

I'm stuck.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $\alpha\in\mathscr{P}_n$ can be written as $$\alpha=\left(\prod_{i\in X\setminus \operatorname{dom}\alpha}(1i)\xi(1i)\right)\hat{\alpha}$$ and $\hat{\alpha}\in\mathscr{T}_n$.

Hence $\mathscr{P}_n=\langle \zeta, \tau, \pi, \xi\rangle$.