# Necessary and sufficient conditions that $\langle \zeta, (ij), \lvert\lvert k\, \ell \rvert\rvert, \xi_M\rangle$ generates $\mathscr{P}_n.$

Tags: functions, permutations, semigroups, monoid, finitely-generated

*Throughout I use [cycle notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and write maps $m:X\to Y$ on the right of their arguments (e.g. $xm=y$ for $m(x)=y$).*

Let $\zeta=(12\dots n)$.

This question is inspired by the following questions:

- [Necessary and Sufficient conditions to generate $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515149/104041)
- [Showing the full transformation semigroup $\mathscr{T}_n=\langle\zeta, \tau, \pi\rangle$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/950124/104041)
- [Showing $\mathscr{P}_n=\langle\zeta, \tau, \pi, \xi\rangle$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245579/104041)

> **Definition 1:** The [*full transformation semigroup*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup) $\mathscr{T}_n$ on the set $N=\{1, \dots,n\}$ is given by all maps $\alpha:N\to N$, together with composition of transformations.
>
> **Definition 2:** For $i\ne j$ in $N$, let $\lvert\lvert i\, j \rvert\rvert$ denote the map $\phi\in\mathscr{T}_n$ for which $$i\phi =j,\quad x\phi=x\quad (x\ne i).$$
>
> **Definition 3:** The *partial transformation semigroup* $\mathscr{P}_n$ is the set of all partial maps from $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ to itself, together with composition of partial transformations.
>
> **Definition 4:** For each subset $M$ of $N=\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$, define $\xi_{M}$ by the identity $1_{N\setminus M}$.

Let me interject by saying I'm not sure if this question makes much sense, so if that's the case, I'm sorry.

> **Question:** Are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $1\le i\le j\le n$, $k, \ell\in N$, and $M\subseteq N$ such that $$\langle \zeta, (ij), \lvert\lvert k\, \ell \rvert\rvert, \xi_M\rangle$$ generates $\mathscr{P}_n$?

*Thoughts:*

I don't have much to offer besides pointing to the lemmas of the questions that inspired this question.

This is not something I think I could solve myself.

The question arose out of curiosity.

I did a module in semigroup theory back in, oh, 2014/2015, and I read about a third of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"* (before starting a PhD in combinatorial group theory). I also did a module in formal languages & automata circa 2012/2013; plenty of monoids were studied then; and my Master's dissertation was on inverse semigroups.

Please help :)

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3248916/104041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete solution to your question can be found in Chapter 3 of the book

O. Ganyushkin and V. Mazorchuk, *Classical finite transformation semigroups. An introduction.* Algebra and Applications, 9. Springer-Verlag London, Ltd., London, 2009. xii+314 pp. ISBN: 978-1-84800-280-7

Here are the relevant results. Let $\mathcal{S}_n$ be the symmetric group of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, let $\mathcal{T}_n$ be the full symmetric semigroup of all transformations of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and let $\mathcal{PT}_n$ be the semigroup of all partial transformations of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

**Lemma 1**. 
Each generating system of $\mathcal{PT}_n$ must contain a generating system of $\mathcal{S}_n$.
If $A$ is an irreducible generating system of $\mathcal{PT}_n$, then $A \cap \mathcal{S}_n$ is an irreducible generating system of
$\mathcal{S}_n$.

**Lemma 2**. Each generating system of $\mathcal{PT}_n$ must contain at least one element of rank $(n − 1)$.

**Theorem 3**.
Let $A$ be a generating system of $\mathcal{T}_n$. Then this system is irreducible if and only if $A = A_1 \cup \{\alpha\}$, where $A_1$ is an irreducible generating system of $\mathcal{S}_n$ and $rank(\alpha) = n − 1$.

**Theorem 4**.
Let $A$ be a generating system of $\mathcal{PT}_n$. Then this system is irreducible if and only if $A = A_1 \cup \{\alpha, \beta\}$, where $A_1$ is an irreducible generating system of $\mathcal{S}_n$, $\alpha$ is a total transformation of rank $n − 1$ and $\beta$ is a partial permutation of rank $n − 1$.

Comment: Thank you. The bounty is as good as yours at this point. I'll award it later on, though, because perhaps there's someone out there who could really get into the details of what this means for $i,j,k,l, M$.