# Show than $(1,k+1), (1,2,3,...,n)$ generate the group $S_n$ if and only if $k$ and $n$ are coprime

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I am able to prove constructively that if $(k,n)=1$ then we can generate $S_n$ but am struggling with the converse.

Comment: Show that the generators preserve the partition into congruence classes mod $(k,n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\geq 2$ and $1\leq a < b \leq n$. Then $S_n$ is generated by the transposition $(ab)$ and the $n$-cycle $(12\dots n)$ if and only if $\gcd(b-a,n)=1$.

For a complete proof see Theorem 2.8 of Keith Conrad's [blurb on Generating Sets](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf).